# If statements to check that variable is a boolean results in "boolean != boolean"

Tags: javascript, error-handling, boolean-logic

I'm attempting to put in some error handing into some of my functions that check whether or not a particular field is enabled or not. I wanted to add some conditional checks to make sure that a particular parameter of the function was always a boolean value (i.e true to verify the field is enabled / false to verify the field is disabled) because I noticed that my functions would not yield errors if a different data type was used.

So I set up a little test code that would also allow the user to use certain strings in place of true boolean values. That looks something like this:
(Note: We're using Squish for GUI testing and using some of their in-house functions)

```
function boolCheck(bool)
{
    var truth = ["true","True","TRUE","T","t"];
    var lies = ["false","False","FALSE","F","f"];

    if (truth.indexOf(bool) !== -1)
    {
        bool = true;
    }
    if (lies.indexOf(bool) !== -1)
    {
        bool = false;
    }
    else if (bool !== true || bool !== false)
    {
        test.fatal("ERROR: " + (typeof bool).toUpperCase() + " is not a BOOLEAN data type.");
    }
}


function main()
{
    boolCheck(true);
}
```

Running this presents the following result in what is essentially the console (test.[something] is basically like printing to the console)

`Fatal ERROR: BOOLEAN is not a BOOLEAN data type.`

That seems, odd to me.

Further, running this in main:

```
function main()
{
    boolCheck("T")
}
```

gives this result:

`Fatal ERROR: BOOLEAN is not a BOOLEAN data type.`

Obviously, there's something wrong with how this is all being handled. Maybe I'm just going about this all the wrong way. Can anyone offer some insight as to why "BOOLEAN" and "BOOLEAN" are not showing up as equal? Or a better way to handle this period? For example, I'd love to think of a good way to wrap this all in a Try/Catch.

Comment: Further, you'd be best to change `if (lies.indexOf(bool) !== -1)` to `else if (lies.indexOf(bool) !== -1)` for completeness.

Comment: @LeeTaylor Why is that? My understanding is that `else if` is only to evaluate if the `if` statements are not met. I want to check both true and false values equally.

Comment: If the first `if` succeeds then why would the second one? Do you anticipate that a value can be both true and false?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple logic error

```
if (bool !== true || bool !== false)
```

So lets read it out loud. If bool is not equal to true or bool is not equal to false, go into this block.

So when bool is `true` it is not false so it will go into the if block.

It needs to be if bool is not euqal to true **AND** bool is not equal to false

Comment: I don't know whether to be glad that my mistakes are usually simple ones or ashamed lol. Thank you for helping me sort that out! I made that change and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Why you not use npm module
[boolean](https://www.npmjs.com/package/boolean)

It's match with your requirement

```
    const boolean = require('boolean');

    console.log(boolean('t')) // true
    console.log(boolean('True')) // true
    console.log(boolean(true)) // true
    console.log(boolean('TrUe')) // true
    console.log(boolean('TRUE')) // true
    console.log(boolean('true')) // true

    console.log(boolean('f')) // false
    console.log(boolean('False')) // false
    console.log(boolean(false)) // false
    console.log(boolean('FaLsE')) // false
    console.log(boolean('FALSE')) // false
    console.log(boolean('false')) // false
```

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer

Comment: @epascarello I keep this in mind in further answering